# display an array which is a result of useCollectionData in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm new to Firebase and practicing with a Chat app. React warns that the list of my messages needs a unique key-id which caused by this line code code:

`{messages && messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}`

I don't understand why it does not take my key={msg.id}.
Any help is appreciated.
Here is a snapshot of my function which causes react console error:

```
function ChatRoom() { 
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState('');

  return (
   <>
    <main>
      {messages && messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}
    </main>
    <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
      <input value={formValue} onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)} placeholder="say something nice" />
      <button type="submit" disabled={!formValue}>️</button>
    </form>
  </>)
}
```

Comment: Are all `msg.id` unique, 100% sure?

Comment: @AseemGautam, thank you!!! Your question answered my problem!! That ID is the issue, the msg does not have any id. Not sure why not, but I'm still following the tutorial. Hope it will reveal more info when I progress more.

Comment: I have also posted a similar answer, if it solves this problem you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely, `msg.id` is **not unique** for all the records. In your case you can use `index` which is available as a 2nd parameter of `map` function -

```
{messages && messages.map((msg, index) => <ChatMessage key={index} message={msg} />)}
```